# Multiple switch option for V12 reverse camera in car

Tags: switches, automotive, analog-switch

I am installing a backup camera into a car.

The instructions say a few things:

1. When wiring it to the reverse lamp, the display (GPS) will switch automatically, but will only work when backing up.
2. When wired to an always-on source, the camera is always on, but the user will have to manually select the camera on the display (GPS.)

It also said sometimes the reverse lamp wire does not provide constant 12V power, so if that is the desired configuration, it might be best to use a relay where the reverse lamp triggers the relay that feeds the camera with an always-on source.

I want the best of both worlds.  I would like to have both the reverse lights AND a switch in the cab be able to turn on the camera.  Is there a way to create an OR gate where if either or both the switch or reverse lights are on, the camera would get power from the always-on source?

Comment: Do you have a link for this camera system?  What is the make/model/year of your vehicle?

Comment: Camera: https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/pn/010-01991-00
Car: 2011 Toyota Corrola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my crude solution, that is not an OR but I'm not concerned to the possible contemporary connection of the 2 relays.
[image]

to make a better solution you can limit the current in the onboard switch.

Comment: It looks like this would work provide me with both relays, is that correct? https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-Channel-Isolated-Optocoupler-Trigger/dp/B00LW15F42

Comment: You could use the switch directly instead of the second relay, if it has a suitable current rating, and routing the wiring permits that....

Comment: this relay module seams good, make a test before, you need just a couple of wires and some switch to simulate all. @user_1818839 yes i agree i don't think camera have an I current demand that oblige us to have a switch near by

Comment: Of course the relay may still be simpler or neater than routing power to the dashboard and back.